# Transport variable by Bundle in Tab

Tags: android, tabs, nullpointerexception, bundle

I have a tabHost `MainActivity` and two A, B activities. In each Tabs I want to transport a string called cityName from MainActivity to A activity. But I always got a `NullPointerException` in Logcat and be forced close T.T

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

private static TabHost tabHost;
public static String selectedCity;
Bundle selectedCityBundle = new Bundle();
Intent selectedCityIntent = new Intent();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources res = getResources();
    selectedCityBundle.putString("CityName", "LA");
    selectedCityIntent.setClass(this, A.class);
    selectedCityIntent.putExtras(selectedCityBundle);
    tabHost = getTabHost();     
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, A.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("A", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.start))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, B.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
            .setIndicator("B", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.weather))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
```

**Class A**

```
public class A extends Activity {

TextView tempNum, cn1, cn2, cn3, ln1, ln2, ln3, city, rainProb;
Intent cityIntent = new Intent();
Bundle cityBundlecityBundle = cityIntent.getExtras();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    tempNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp);
    rainProb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raining);
    cn1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone1News1);
    cn2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone1News2);
    cn3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone1News3);
    ln1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone2News1);
    ln2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone2News2);
    ln3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone2News3);
    city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);      
    city.setText(cityBundle.getString("CityName"));
    //Always got error NullPointerException here
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently putting a bundle inside another bundle. Pass your city name like this instead:

```
selectedCityIntent.putExtra("CityName", "LA");
```

And your code should run well.

**Edit:**

You are not capturing the intent too, you just create a new one in your code. In your class A, get the bundle like this:

```
Bundle cityBundle;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    cityBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    tempNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp);
    rainProb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raining);
    cn1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone1News1);
    cn2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone1News2);
    cn3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone1News3);
    ln1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone2News1);
    ln2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone2News2);
    ln3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zone2News3);
    city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);      
    city.setText(cityBundle.getString("CityName"));
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Ok there are also problems when you supply the intent to the tab. You did not include your selectedCityBundle. Since you are using too many bundles unnecessarily, see the code below for `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

private static TabHost tabHost;
public static String selectedCity;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources res = getResources();
    tabHost = getTabHost();     
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;
    intent= new Intent().setClass(this, A.class);
    intent.putExtra("CityName", "LA");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("A", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.start))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, B.class);
    intent.putExtra("CityName", "LA");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
            .setIndicator("B", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.weather))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
```

Please note that I am not sure if the intent and spec and be reused like this. If you find any errors when changing tab, try to create a new intent and spec in different variables for each tab.

Comment: Can't run. Still got NullPointerException in the same line :(

Comment: I've tried this way. But there is an error in getIntent() "The method is undefined for the type A"

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String string = bundle.getString("CityName");
 city.setText(string);
```

Comment: I always can't use "getIntent().getExtras();" way in A activity. "The method is undefined for the type A" on getIntent()